# Explicitly close inline tag

Tags: pug

Is it possible to close an inline tag explicitly? For example, to save space, I would like to produce the following using 1 line of jade:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create</a>
```

I thought this would work, but it seems to break jade:

```
a(href="#"): i.fa.fa-plus/ Create
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using `Tag Interpolation`:
http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

```
a(href="#") #[i.fa.fa-plus] Create
```